# Cocos2D 2.0 - Changing color of a CCParticle

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem, cctexturecache

So after messing around with my game, there's a thing that I wanted to share with you that I discovered about CCParticle.

- How do I change the color of the particles in a CCParticleSystem?
- When I was on cocos 1.x, I could change it with startColor, endColor, but in 2.0, whenever I do it, it stays black. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A:In Cocos2D 2.0, it stays the same, but unlike in 1.x, you must first make sure that the particle texture is white, because otherwise it will not blend with the color you want! Make sure too that the texture is correctly added, because if not, it will show big black pixels and that's probably not the result you want!

Comment: o rly? one of my particle textures is grey, and color changes work fine.

Comment: Yeah well, I should have said that it works in a greyscale too, but you won't get the exact same color as the rgb values. (i.e If you go in Photoshop and enter the RGB value {212,0,0}, you'll get a lighter red than you would in your game)